# Overriding spring beans with the same Qualifier Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 configuration classes in my spring application.
`Configuration` and `AnotherConfiguration`. The `AnotherConfiguration` is conditioned to create beans only if a certain parameter is provided (this is handled by the `ConditionalOnClass` annotation).

Configuration.java

```
@Configuration 
public class Configuration {

@Bean
    public Stage testStage() {
          return someStage1;
    }

@Bean
    public Stage testStage2() {
          return someStage2;
    }

}
```

AnotherConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass()
public class AnotherConfiguration {

@Bean
    public Stage testStage2() {
          return newStage2;
    }

}
```

The use case is that if I supply an argument that satisfies the Conditional argument for `AnotherConfiguration`, `newStage2` should be returned to all the classes expecting a `testStage2` bean. But currently, the `testStage2` bean is being resolved from `Configuration` class instead of being overridden by `AnotherConfiguration`.

I have tried adding the `@Primary` annotation to the definition in `AnotherConfiguration` but that just resolves `newStage2` to all the classes expecting bean of type `Stage` irrespective of the qualifier. Is there a way to instruct spring to override bean definitions only of the same QualifierName (here `testStage2`.

Due to the project constraints, I cannot make changes to `Configuration.java` but can make any change to `AnotherConfiguration.java` keeping the name (`testStage2()`) same.

Comment: read [this](https://brudenko.com/spring-bean-override). bean overriding is bad and cannot be determined in any way. Try to work around it

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recomend it but

use a conditional instead of an onClass because that will always be true without params

```
public class Cond implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then define the overridden bean to load into the context

```
@Component("testStage2")
@Conditional(value = Cond.class)
@Primary
public class AnotherStage extends Stage {
    public AnotherStage(){
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Sorry bean style

```
@Configuration
public class AnotherConfiguration {
    @Bean("testBean2")
    @Conditional(value = Cond.class)
    @Primary
    public Stage testStage2() {
      return newStage2;
    }

}
```